# Использование фильтрации в паре с сортировкой

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть `QTableView` и кастомная модель для него. В качестве модели, я использую класс, унаследованный от `QSortFilterProxyModel` с переопределенными методами `filterAcceptsRow` и `lessThan`. Мне нужно фильтровать модель по некому критерию, после чего сортировать ее.
С фильтрацией проблем нет. Подключился к сигналам `rowsAboutToBeRemoved` и `rowsInserted`, после чего все нормально работало. Однако, когда я сделал сортировку, то оказалось, что модель не эмитит сигналы `rowsAboutToBeMoved` или `rowsMoved`, которые логичны при сортировки, поэтому модель сначала сортируется (визуально), а потом фильтрует отсортированную последовательность не правильно.

---

Например, у меня была модель состоящая из нескольких элементов:
`B X Z C d a h`
И я хочу отсортировать их по алфавиту и оставить только буквы верхнего регистра.
Тогда, если использовать только фильтрацию, то вызовется сигнал, `rowsAboutToBeRemoved` с `start = 4; end = 6` и после фильтрации останется
`B D Z C` (как и должно быть)
Но, если мы добавим туда сортировку, то он сначала отсортирует их по алфавиту, а потом вызовет этот же сигнал с такими же `start` и `end`.
`a B C d h X Z` -> `a B C d`.

В чем прикол?

P.S. Кода очень много для примеров, если нужно будет что-то конкретное - пишите.